# gitignore path to external framework

Tags: ios, xcode, git, gitignore

I have an xcode ios repository which I share with another developer.

In this project we use a framework sdk which is not part of the system so it is referred froms some other directory on our hard disc.

The problem is that the path to this framework is different on each computer so I thought I can just add the path to the external framework to the gitignore file so we do not have to adjust the correct manually every time we pull from github?

Do you see another solution?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than depend on your external framework being present on a developer's computer tu could add it as a submodules to the repository. This has advantages:

- the framework is added at a defined path relative to the project.
- the version of the framework being used is specified so all developers are using the same version.

Comment: thats a good point. Actually the external sdk is 100 MB and I don't want to upload the entire framework to github.

Comment: 100 Mb isn't that much, and I don't think there is a GitHub limit you will breach by putting it on there.